# "plugin" composer project, dependencies to be able to access main project

Tags: php, composer-php

So I can't quite figure this one out. We have an API as a composer project.
No we which to add functionality to this API in a modular fashion creating separate composer projects for each module.

But how do I resolve dependencies while developing? Each module need access to the "core" API project to be able to test out code.

The current API is not a real composer package yet. But my initial thought is to create a new package for the module I'm about to develope, and then add a dev-dependency for the "core" API.

Or how should I do it?

Comment: sounds right: dev dependencies are often used for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

Are your modules standalone resp. without the "Core" package usable?
I suppose not, so the "Core" module is a dependency for each of your modules.
Ergo the "you/core" package needs to be in the require block of composer.json of every module.

Note that this is not a dev-dependancy then, because i suppose your module wouldnt be usable without the core package.
Phpunit is a classic dev-dependency because the functionality of your module would still work if there would be no phpunit.

To test &  develop the module, you would run a `composer install` in your module project folder to fetch all dependencies into a vendor folder. Then you can develop and have all your dependencies present. You would need to require the composer autoloader, though. F.e in your phpunit.xml.dist.

Dont forget to add `vendor` to your .gitignore

Comment: As you said: The modules are not stand-alone at all. The are totally dependent on the core package. I just don't want it in core. It's just a question of how to develop the modules and still be able to try it out while coding.

Comment: you could develop the module standalone via tests first and than integrate it in the project. then you could simply fix & code in the vendor folder of your project until it works and merge the changes back to the standalone module folder, do some more tests on the changes and commit and push there. then make a composer update of you module package in the project again.